# Convert jpg image into pdf base64 without saving any file

Tags: python, pdf, jpeg

How can I convert an image into pdf base64 without saving it locally?

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-image-to-pdf-using-img2pdf-module/